# Compiling C++ inside a folder in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-netbook, compiling, c++, c

I have some question about compiling .cpp inside a folder, it says

> first.cpp No such file or directory

but when I run it in home it compiles. Any settings I might have left out? Thanks.

Here's the Terminal output ([view it bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbm8S.png)):
[image]

```
law@ubuntu:~$ ls
android-sdk   Downloads         Pictures        test        wallpapers
android-sdks  eclipse           Public          tomcat      workspace
Desktop       examples.desktop  sourcecodescpp  Ubuntu One
Documents     Music             Templates       Videos
law@ubuntu:~$ dir sourcecodescpp
first.cpp
law@ubuntu:~$ g++ first.cpp
g++: error: first.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
law@ubuntu:~$ ./a/out
bash: ./a/out: No such file or directory
law@ubuntu:~$ ls
android-sdk   Downloads         Pictures        test        wallpapers
android-sdks  eclipse           Public          tomcat      workspace
Desktop       examples.desktop  sourcecodescpp  Ubuntu One
Documents     Music             Templates       Videos
law@ubuntu:~$ dir ls
dir: cannot access ls: No such file or directory
law@ubuntu:~$ ls
android-sdk   Downloads         Music           Templates   Videos
android-sdks  eclipse           Pictures        test        wallpapers
Desktop       examples.desktop  Public          tomcat      workspace
Documents     first.cpp         sourcecodescpp  Ubuntu One
law@ubuntu:~$ g++ first.cpp
law@ubuntu:~$ ./a.out
Hello World!law@ubuntu:~$ ^C
law@ubuntu:~$ ^C
law@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were in your home folder (`/home/law`) when you issued the `g++ first.cpp` command. But `first.cpp` is located in the `sourcecodescpp` folder. To compile `first.cpp`, you must either enter the folder that contains it:

```
cd sourcecodescpp
```

(Then the output file will, by default, be created inside `sourcecodescpp`.)

Or qualify its name with the name of the folder that contains it:

```
g++ sourcecodescpp/first.cpp
```

(Then the output file will, by default, be created inside your home folder.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to move (change directory, or `cd`) into the `sourcecodescpp` dirctory first, to run/compile any files in there. For that please run

```
cd sourcecodescpp
```

from the Terminal and now you'll be in that directory.

Now you can run

```
g++ first.cpp
```

to compile and

```
./a.out
```

to run.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, you can give full path to your cpp file to avoid such error.

I think even following should work:

```
g++ /home/yourdirectory/first.cpp
```

Comment: `g++ /home/<username>/yourdirectory/first.cpp` should be used in his case. Or rather  `g++ ~/yourdirectory/first.cpp`   Where `~` is a replacement for the path to user's home directory.